# Haskell: How to convert a list to a list where each element is a tuple of its location in the list and the original data?

Tags: haskell

I need to convert a list to a list where each element is a tuple of its location in the list and the original data.Such as

```
[a,b,c,d] -> [(1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,d)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What didn't work?  Hint: check out the functions in Data.List on Hackage.

Comment: If you can't use Data.List, then think recursion.

Comment: Why start with `1`? Why not `0`? Or 42? Think about it, I am trying to lead you to a solution with this question!

Comment: I'd argue that this question is sufficiently different to not be a duplicate. The other question specifically desired to implement their own function, whereas this question is easily answered with Haskell's default functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method I can conceive of is using the `zip` function. It takes two lists as arguments and returns a list of tuples. Pair that with a range `[1..]` and you have what you desire:

```
zip [1..] [a,b,c,d]
```

Will return

```
[(1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,d)]
```